# Automatically close windows explorer

Tags: c#, windows, explorer

i am trying to write a program that close explorer then runs another program.
i am getting a problem when trying to close explorer using the following code:

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
                if (p.MainModule.ModuleName.Contains("explorer"))
                    p.Kill();
```

can somebody please let me know why it is doing this and provide a solution
CHEERS

p.s. this is not a malicous program, it is going to run a game that doesn't work properly when explorer is in the background

Comment: For future reference, which game is that?

Comment: Worms Armageddon - New Edition. i think the problems is only with windows 7. still a very good game

Comment: What problem are you getting?  Note that when you kill the shell process, it's usually restarted automatically.

Comment: Win32Exception - Access is denied

Comment: **WHY** doesn't it work when explorer is running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you can have multiple versions of Explorer running at any one point in time... and you usually need at least one of them. The shell that hosts the Start Menu is actually an instance of Explorer. So if you close all instances of Explorer, you'll also be shutting down the main shell, which is not what you want to do.

However, the fastest way to do get all instances of Explorer and kill them is:

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer"))
{
   p.Kill();
}
```

Comment: this is what i want to do, i do it manually at the moment in order to play the game. i thought it would be nicer if i had one button to close explorer then start the game and another to start explorer

Comment: @harryovers - OK... I made an edit to show the proper code then.

Comment: @harryovers - Also as was mentioned in a different comment... the Shell generally restarts automatically if it's shut down... so this may not work very well.

Comment: it is restarting every time, nevermind. will just have to do it manually

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple undocumented way to exit explorer cleanly, see also question [Gracefully Exit Explorer (Programmatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689904/gracefully-exit-explorer-programmatically/6246182). It is intended for developers working on shell extensions.

The procedure is different for Windows XP and Windows 7:

Windows XP:
Open the shutdown dialog (Start > Shutdown), then cancel the dialog pressing CTRL-SHIFT-ALT-ESC  (or hold down CTRL-SHIFT-ALT and press the  Button with the mouse).

Windows 7:
Open the Start menu and then hold CTRL-SHIFT while right-klicking into the empty area of the start menu, see [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689904/gracefully-exit-explorer-programmatically/6246182). A context menu appears, where the second entry is 'Exit Explorer' (without CTRL-SHIFT the context menu has only one entry)

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT is the admin key modifier, you can run programs as admin by holding them and clicking the program. al though this would work i used a proram called task kill and the then used a bash script to kill explorer and start the program i wanted in one click

Answer (score 0):

> p.s. this is not a malicous program, it is going to run a game that doesn't work properly when explorer is in the background

Explorer is a critical Windows component. You should debug why you have problems when Explorer is running, and fix those.

Killing Explorer will cause severe problems for your users.