# C# - Disable balloon tips

Tags: c#, balloon

I would like to create an application which disables balloon tips in my system by editing the registry (there is another way?). But I want that it would be take place immediatly and without restart/log off.

Thank you!

Comment: gotta love the 'Ballon' tag!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What isn't working?  Currently this question reads like a request for someone to write this for you, which isn't likely to happen.

Comment: Hi, I know how to edit the registry from my application but dont know how to make the changes take place immediatly and without restart/log off.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the value of EnableBalloonTips in the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced to 0. You can use the [RegistryKey class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for that.

Then you can use [a method to exit Windows Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689904/gracefully-exit-explorer-programmatically) and start Windows Explorer again using Process.Start.

However you should ask for user's permission before you restart Windows Explorer.

Comment: **Do not interfere with the user's `explorer` process**

Comment: I think it is OK if the user is asked before Windows Explorer is restarted.

Comment: You think so, but the OP probably doesn't.  You should say that explicitly in your answer, preferably in bold or italics